# ArcMap Raster to NetCDF - lat/long

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, coordinate-system, netcdf

I need to convert a few files which are projected in WGS84 into netCDF. NetCDF requires lat/long. I am a bit confused on how the process is handled by ArcMap especially after looking at the online online Help for Arc10.2. Should I convert my raster to lat long projection before converting the file to netcdf or is the lat long conversion is automatically carried out when using the Raster to netCDF tool?

Comment: NetCDF as a format does not require lat/lon so no, the tool won't automatically convert the raster. See third sentence in [this topic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00460000000p000000).

Comment: thanks mkennedy, I have to have lat/lon coordinated in my netCDF file for for running simulations with WRF. What do you mean by 'does not require lat/lon'. The link you suggested says that 'The Raster to NetCDF tool always creates a new netCDF' therefore what you mean by 'won't automatically convert the raster'. Perhaps to make it clearer any doubts about my objective, I shall rephrase my sentence; I have a file in raster format and need to run a model in WRF which only accepts netCDF as valid input. How do I convert my raster to netCDF and have lat/lon coordinated in the netCDF file? Thank yo

Comment: @John If you are the same John as the original poster, then please [merge your two accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can edit the question: that will make it much clearer than putting essential information in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to input to WRF, then yes, you should convert to Spatial Reference GCS_WGS_1984 in ArcMAP, and then output to NetCDF using the ArcToolbox=>"Multidimensional Tools"=>"Raster to NetCDF" tool.  "lon" and "lat" should already be there, and you can change the name of the variable and set the units as well (see attached screengrab where I saved some DEM data as NetCDF).

[image: ArcMAP raster2netcdf]

The resulting file will be CF-compliant, as evidenced below, where I open the ArcMAP-generated NetCDF file in Unidata's ToolsUI app:

[image: ArcMAP generated netcdf in Unidata ToolsUI]